# serving react files with express

Tags: reactjs, express

This is my first time serving react files with express.js. The build has been run and the server is listening, but I cant figure out why the components aren't being injected into the html file. Instead it's rendering just the html template.

Here is a picture of my build folder:

[build folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Kna.png)

Here is my index.js file from my server folder:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan(':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method 
:url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] :response-time 
ms'))

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'..', 'build', 'index.html'))
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

this what I see in the console:

[served page console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBhaO.png)

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your script tag src is wrong. Should be `src="/js/main.33e13313.js"`. How are you setting your script src?

Comment: Thanks for your response!.It defaults to that when I npm run build. Tried changing it to your suggestion and still same issue

Answer (score -2):

See the following link

[react-express-boilerplate](https://github.com/pjt3591oo/react-express-boilerplate)

Add the following code to `index.html` file

```
<script src="src="/js/main.33e13313.js""></script>
```

`main.33e13313.js` is a file that packages js with webpack.

Your package.json file will be set as follow:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf build public/bundle.js",
    "build": "babel server --out-dir build && webpack",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production supervisor ./build/main.js",
    "development": "NODE_ENV=development node ./build/main.js"
  },
```

You will use npm run build to run.

You can use babel to change es6 to es5. this is **build** tool.

You can use webpack to package JavaScript files. packagig is bundles JavaScript files into one file. this is **packaging** tool.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Really appreciate it